# HTML field in Json request

Tags: html, json, smtp

I am sending email through SMTP2GO api whose request is in JSON; but the email received has all the tags of html in its body. Does SMTP support html tags?
What should i do; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with SMTP2GO api. But in most case you should decode any json response before display it as html.

Something like

```
$json = json_decode('response from server');
// search for strings you want to display.
var_dump($json);
// display string 
echo $json->id->body;
```

Comment: Thnx Drunken
But i am sending json request that has a field of email body in html

Comment: @HarisAsadBajwa Then you should do something to decode it before sending the request. Actually not much that I can do to understand your problem if you not inform your code and things you have already done. Please edit your question if possible.